# Running cmd.exe from Powershell and passing another exe application as a Parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters, exe

Ok so I have been looking for an example on how to do the following but can't seems to find the correct answer. I have found a lot of things that are close but won't work. This code is being run from within a PowerShell script if matters or makes a difference.

Here is the code snip:

`Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -ArgumentList /k "msdgen170.exe" -Wait -WindowStyle Maximized -Verb RunAs -WorkingDirectory "C:\Program Files (x86)\3E\msdgen"`

It works as far starting the cmd window but I can't seem to get the msdgen170.exe application to be passed to the window. It opens and stops at a prompt. I have tried the & but that doesn't work either.

What am I missing?

Thanks for helping to point me in the correct direction.

Comment: The issue is with the parameters for msdgen170.exe.  Maybe the Wait is the issue.  You need to run the app in a mode that doesn't prompt or powershell needs to send something to standard input.

Comment: You probably want `-ArgumentList "/c","msdgen170.exe"`

Comment: Thanks that seems to do the trick! I have no idea why I didn't try it... :)